# Automatic mute speakers after headphones unplugged

Tags: sound, mute

Does any one know of a way to mute the speakers when headphones are unplugged?

I tried this method https://askubuntu.com/a/697631/527877, but its not working.

Comment: Ubuntu should have separate volumes for when an audio device is plugged in and when one isn't. You could just set your volume to `mute` and then plug the headphones in.

Comment: I may forget to do this, I would like this to happen automatically.

Comment: What about: http://askubuntu.com/questions/133809/mute-sound-on-headphone-unplug

Comment: I would like to do through /etc/acpi/events/, but 
event=jack/*
action=amixer sset Master playback 0% %e
dont work too