# a start job is running for /boot/efi (1.30 min slow boot time)

Tags: boot, dual-boot

I am experiencing very slow boot times on reboot and I have to manually restart 2-3 times to get to a regular boot for it to boot properly. This just started one day and has been happening ever since (before this problem started, the system would boot in 5secs from the time the Ubuntu logo appeared on the screen).
I am getting "a start job is running for /boot/efi" at the start and then several lines with journal checking and so on.

I have looked on other threads people reporting the same issue and it seems to be caused by a /etc/fstab erroneous uuid.
But I checked sudo blkid and /etc/fstab output and they seem to match.

sudo blkid output:

```
/dev/loop0: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop1: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop2: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop3: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop4: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop5: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop6: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop7: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/nvme0n1p1: LABEL="SYSTEM" UUID="40F6-B9B6" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI system partition" PARTUUID="96888f3a-32b4-4c29-a97a-0a2752032570"
/dev/nvme0n1p3: LABEL="Windows" UUID="AEB4F937B4F9029F" TYPE="ntfs" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="69a69e0a-938c-42ce-9226-be4c125ee402"
/dev/nvme0n1p4: LABEL="WinRE_DRV" UUID="E0B4F9BEB4F9976E" TYPE="ntfs" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="8c6c7f7d-4df1-40cc-a2b1-f0dc3013f00a"
/dev/nvme0n1p5: UUID="d4d0677a-3d4f-4c7c-96f4-66ed734a5a3d" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="4452c614-1e43-4141-91f7-46c009f9f177"
/dev/nvme0n1p6: UUID="a718d4e2-923d-4377-ad85-99693a258718" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="9d01bb23-5e03-4854-802d-de338d04a749"
/dev/loop8: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop9: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop10: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop11: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop12: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop13: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop14: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop15: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop16: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop17: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop18: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop19: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop20: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop21: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop22: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop23: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop24: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop25: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop26: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop27: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop28: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop29: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop30: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop31: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop32: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop33: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop34: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop35: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop36: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop37: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop38: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop39: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop40: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop41: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop42: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop43: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop44: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop45: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop46: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop47: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop48: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop49: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop50: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/nvme0n1: PTUUID="6b27bf65-2dd5-46ec-aaa7-7a757af74c48" PTTYPE="gpt"
/dev/nvme0n1p2: PARTLABEL="Microsoft reserved partition" PARTUUID="c8291373-5fbb-4874-b897-fc75feb2b9f6"
```

/etc/fstab:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/nvme0n1p5 during installation
UUID=d4d0677a-3d4f-4c7c-96f4-66ed734a5a3d /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/nvme0n1p1 during installation
UUID=40F6-B9B6  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
# swap was on /dev/nvme0n1p6 during installation
UUID=a718d4e2-923d-4377-ad85-99693a258718 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

Does anyone know what is causing this?
Edit: I'm on Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: You have a lot of snaps, the loop entries. I also use Kubuntu which is a bit faster loading. Some other settings to review: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1284302/is-it-possible-to-make-ubuntu-20-04-boot-faster  What version & flavor of Ubuntu?

Comment: Do the loop entries hurt? I don't know what generated them. I'm on Ubuntu 18.04. Btw before this problem started it would boot in 5secs from the time the Ubuntu logo appeared on the screen, now it's way more than 1.30 mins (something like 3mins) and it won't boot properly the first 2-3 times.

Comment: Each loop entry is a snap. I prefer to use .deb, but Ubuntu now defaults to snaps for many applications.

Comment: Every thread that I'm reading suggests it's a problem with /etc/fstab not having the right entries but my entries match the blkid output (as shown in the paste)! So I don't know what to fix.

I'm not complaining about a "slow boot" actually, it starts in emergency mode everytime, one day something happened (didn't do anything different so I can't pinpoint the reason behind it) and boot now takes 1.30-3 mins instead of the normal 5secs. Something is 
 failing because it says a start job is running for dev-disk-by.. like this thread: https://askubuntu.com/questions/7110...or-dev-disk-by

Comment: Another thread with the same problem: https://askubuntu.com/questions/960790/stuck-in-emergency-mode-and-nothing-works  
The problem is that they seemed to be having mismatched /etc/fstab entries whereas I do not as far as I can see unless I'm missing something..

Comment: I think I have to manually run fsck on the linux partitions (from a usb stick while they're unmounted)..

Comment: I tried manually fsck -y every partition (did this using a live usb stick while the ssd drive was unmounted). fsck reports that the root ext4 filesystem is clean. But on boot I get the same thing, it keeps booting into emergency mode. /etc/fstab looks good to me and I don't know what else to try. I would appreciate it if anyone can help!